# Which commit was a specific release on rubygems created from?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to create a release history, how can I identify which commit a specific version of a gem was created from on rubygems.com? When I extract the *.gem archive it does not include any logging of the commit.

EDIT: The releases were pushed to rubygems without updating the github repo with the relevant tags, I want to backfill github with the appropriate release tags.

Comment: Why do you assume the gem was created from a commit?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Excellent point, it may have been created from the current state of the checked out branch.

Comment: Or without any version control system at all. Sadly, "ZIP files with names like `myproject_123_final45_reallyfinal_63_patch.zip`" is still by far the most widely-used method of version control, and "no version control at all" is even more popular than that.

Comment: how about post a link to rubygems gem you're talking about and also the github repo assuming there is one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: You cannot!

Versions of a gem on Rubygems and commits or tags in Git are two totally different concepts and have nothing in common.

You already discovered that the gem doesn't contain any information about the use of git or a specific commit. And if you think about that, it makes sense that gems do not contain information about the version control system that was used:

- There is no need to use Rubygems and Git at the same time. Actually, there is no need to use any version control system at all when you build gems.
- And even if the author used a version control system, there are other version control systems – like SVN or Mercurial for example.
- Even if the author used Git to keep track of their source code changes, they could still create and upload multiple different versions of the gem without doing a single git commit in the meantime.
- And even if the author did a commit for every gem version, then – depending on the configuration of the gem and the git repository – both systems can include files which exist on one system but not on the other.

That said, the assumption that a specific gem version corresponds with a specific git commit is just valid.

Answer (score 0):

Normally there will be a link to the source code on the gem page of [rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org)

From there you should be taken to the repo, for example if you visit https://rubygems.org/gems/devise  you will see link on the right side of the page that says `Source Code` which should link to

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/

Then you can just click on `releases` at the top of the repo or go to 
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/releases

There you will see the commit the release was built from.

If you just download the .gem file from rubygems.org that will only include the gem code itself and not the git history whatsoever.  If you want the full git history you should clone the repo to your local machine.  To do so, click on the `Clone or download` button at the top of the repo's home page.  If you copy the url from there, can just go to your terminal and type

```
git clone <paste repo url here>
```

Comment: The author created the release locally pushed it to rubygems but did not update github, I'm trying to backfill github with release tags.

Comment: What does "backfill" even mean? How does someone do development on open source without using git version control? If there is not git repo, how are you going to have any commit history?

Comment: meaning they pushed the release from their local dev machine directly to rubygems then did not update github.com with the same tags. rubygems is not dependent on github.com